# Eloquent duplicating rows when saving to database - laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am having this issue when ever I save to the database the row gets duplicated even if the array contains one index position. Am I missing something here?

```
 foreach($params['service'] as $key => $value){
    $data['name'] = $value;
    $data['price'] = $params['price'][$key];  
    $data['business_id'] = $params['business_id'];
    $service = new  Service($data);
    $service->save();
}
```

data of $params

```
array:5 [▼
  "business_id" => "1"
  "service" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "web development"
  ]
  "price" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "R4500"
  ]
  "submit" => null
]
```

these are the duplicates

```
1   web development     R4500   1   2018-08-30 07:24:34     2018-08-30 07:24:34
2   web development     R4500   1   2018-08-30 07:24:34     2018-08-30 07:24:34
```

unfortunately the answer provided by @Rathod also produces duplicates but I noticed that when I add multiple data to the array as shown below it saves without duplicates.

```
array:5 [▼
  "business_id" => "1"
  "user_id" => "1"
  "service" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "web development"
    1 => "mobile development"
    2 => "internet marketing"
  ]
  "price" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "R4500"
    1 => "R8900"
    2 => "R5600"
  ]
  "submit" => null
]
```

here's the full function

```
 public function createService(array $params) : Service
{
  // dd($params);
    try {
      foreach($params['service'] as $key => $value){
        $service = new Service();
        $service->service = $value;
        $service->price = $params['price'][$key];
        $service->business_id = $params['business_id'];
        $service->save();
    }
      return $service;

    } catch (QueryException $e) {
        throw new CreateServiceInvalidArgumentException($e->getMessage(), 500, $e);
    }

  }
```

Comment: can you show data of $params?

Comment: `array:5 [▼
  "business_id" => "1"
  "service" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "web development"
  ]
  "price" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "R4500"
  ]
  "submit" => null
]`

Comment: In Service Model which columns are there?

Comment: These are the columns in the service model

            `$data['service'] 
            $data['price'] 
            $data['business_id'] `

Comment: it look fine, are you sure your service only have one array?

Comment: If this is a controller method, please can you add all of it to your question.

Comment: yeah, your code looks fine according to the $params data that u have provided.

Answer (score 0):

**Try following simple way:**

```
foreach($params['service'] as $key => $value){
    $service = new Service();
    $service->name = $value;
    $service->price = $params['price'][$key];
    $service->business_id = $params['business_id'];
    $service->save();
}
```

I hope it works fine.

Comment: @Rathod

unfortunately it still duplicates but I noticed that when I add multiple data to the array as shown below it saves without duplicates.

array:5 [▼
  "business_id" => "1"
  "user_id" => "1"
  "service" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "web development"
    1 => "mobile development"
    2 => "internet marketing"
  ]
  "price" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "R4500"
    1 => "R8900"
    2 => "R5600"
  ]
  "submit" => null
]

Comment: `$param = [
  "business_id" => "1",
  "service" => [
    0 => "web development"
  ],
  "price" => [
    0 => "R4500"
  ]  
];

$counter = 0;
foreach($param['service'] as $key => $value){
    $counter++;
}

echo $counter;` **It will returns 1**

Comment: It does yes, I did something similar in a different class and it worked is unfortunate it doesn't want to work in this instance!

Answer (score 0):

Those moments I want to slap myself for being stupid... I just noticed I was sending the same data via ajax.. I must have forgotten I had done that.Thanks a lot to everyone for taking your time to look at this for me.